# What is the difference between une devinette, un rébus et une charade?

Tags: vocabulaire, jeux

I am wondering if I could use the words une devinette, un rébus et une charade with the same meaning or there is a difference between them?!

Comment: Devinette est un nom générique. Un rébus est un genre particulier de devinette, une charade un autre. Tu peux donc utiliser *devinette* en place de *rébus* ou de *charade* Tu seras juste moins précise. Pour les noms particuliers que peuvent porter les devinettes, non, on ne peut remplacer l'un par l'autre et je t'invite sur n'importe quel bon dictionnaire pour en saisir les nuances.

Comment: @acoswt merci beaucoup! Pourriez-vous me présenter un bon dictionnaire s'il vous plaît?

Comment: J'ulise pour ma part très souvent le Trésor de la langue française, accessible gratuitement ici : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ c'est une référence. J'aime beaucoup le Littré accessible gratuitement ici : https://www.littre.org/ (une référence aussi mais... d'un autre siècle...) Pour les mots récents, en accès gratuit il reste toujours le wikitionnaire. On fait beaucoup mieux que ce dernier évidement mais... c'est payant. Je recommanderais aussi volontiers le Dictionnaire de L'Académie Française, référence parmi les références, d'accès gratuit aussi mais la dernière édition est incomplète.

Answer (score 4):

Charade et rébus sont deux types de devinettes qui se basent sur la phonétique (il faut trouver un mot ou une phrase, composés à partir de son ou de mots).

Le rébus est visuel: les sons ou les mots sont représentés pas des images, des dessins ou des caractères. Exemple:

> [image] [image]

La charade est textuelle: les différents mots doivent être devinés sur base d'une définition. Exemple:

> Mon premier est un petit félin.
>
> Mon deuxième est un rongeur.
>
> Mon troisième vient après un.
>
> Mon tout est une devinette.